# not able to execute python.3.5.1 on centos

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos

I installed python3.5.1 on CentOS

towards the end of the installation here is what I see

```
/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Include/weakrefobject.h /usr/local/include/python3.5m
/bin/install -c -m 644 pyconfig.h /usr/local/include/python3.5m/pyconfig.h
/bin/install -c -m 644 Modules/config.c /usr/local/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/config.c
/bin/install -c -m 644 Programs/python.o /usr/local/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/python.o
/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Modules/config.c.in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/config.c.in
/bin/install -c -m 644 Makefile /usr/local/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/Makefile
/bin/install -c -m 644 Modules/Setup /usr/local/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/Setup
/bin/install -c -m 644 Modules/Setup.local /usr/local/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/Setup.local
/bin/install -c -m 644 Modules/Setup.config /usr/local/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/Setup.config
/bin/install -c -m 644 Misc/python.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.5.pc
/bin/install -c ./Modules/makesetup /usr/local/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/makesetup
/bin/install -c ./install-sh /usr/local/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/install-sh
/bin/install -c python-config.py /usr/local/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m/python-config.py
/bin/install -c python-config /usr/local/bin/python3.5m-config
./python -E ./setup.py install \
        --prefix=/usr/local \
        --install-scripts=/usr/local/bin \
        --install-platlib=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload \
        --root=/
running install
running build
running build_ext
INFO: Can't locate Tcl/Tk libs and/or headers
**Python build finished successfully!**
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_bz2                  _curses               _curses_panel      
_dbm                  _gdbm                 _lzma              
_sqlite3              _ssl                  _tkinter           
readline              zlib                                     
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
running build_scripts

copying and adjusting /home/kumar/Python-3.5.1/Tools/scripts/pydoc3 -> build/scripts-3.5
copying and adjusting /home/kumar/Python-3.5.1/Tools/scripts/idle3 -> build/scripts-3.5
copying and adjusting /home/kumar/Python-3.5.1/Tools/scripts/2to3 -> build/scripts-3.5
copying and adjusting /home/kumar/Python-3.5.1/Tools/scripts/pyvenv -> build/scripts-3.5
changing mode of build/scripts-3.5/pydoc3 from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-3.5/idle3 from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-3.5/2to3 from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-3.5/pyvenv from 644 to 755
renaming build/scripts-3.5/pydoc3 to build/scripts-3.5/pydoc3.5
renaming build/scripts-3.5/idle3 to build/scripts-3.5/idle3.5
renaming build/scripts-3.5/2to3 to build/scripts-3.5/2to3-3.5
renaming build/scripts-3.5/pyvenv to build/scripts-3.5/pyvenv-3.5
running install_lib
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/_sysconfigdata.py -> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload
creating /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/__pycache__
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/__pycache__/_sysconfigdata.cpython-35.pyc -> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynloa
d/__pycache__
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/__pycache__/_sysconfigdata.cpython-35.opt-1.pyc -> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-
dynload/__pycache__
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/__pycache__/_sysconfigdata.cpython-35.opt-2.pyc -> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-
dynload/__pycache__
changing mode of /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_sysconfigdata.py to 644
```

a few more lines that say changing mode and then towards the end this

```
changing mode of /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_codecs_iso2022.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_decimal.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_multiprocessing.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/ossaudiodev.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/xxlimited.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/ to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/__pycache__ to 755
running install_scripts
copying build/scripts-3.5/pydoc3.5 -> /usr/local/bin
copying build/scripts-3.5/idle3.5 -> /usr/local/bin
copying build/scripts-3.5/2to3-3.5 -> /usr/local/bin
copying build/scripts-3.5/pyvenv-3.5 -> /usr/local/bin
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/pydoc3.5 to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/idle3.5 to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/2to3-3.5 to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/pyvenv-3.5 to 755
rm /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_sysconfigdata.py
rm -r /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/__pycache__
/bin/install -c -m 644 ./Misc/python.man \
        /usr/local/share/man/man1/python3.5.1
if test "xupgrade" != "xno"  ; then \
        case upgrade in \
                upgrade) ensurepip="--altinstall --upgrade" ;; \
                install|*) ensurepip="--altinstall" ;; \
        esac; \
         ./python -E -m ensurepip \
                $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
fi
Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 7.1.2 requires SSL/TLS
```

From what I understand python is installed successfully

But when I say # python3 or #python3.5 or #python3.5.1 (from root) it simply says

```
-bash: python3.5: command not found
```

I have not modified the installation path or anything so is installed on /usr/local...please see attached.

I followed the instructions at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4

and had run the command

```
$make altinstall
```

should I be instead running ?

```
$make && make altinstall
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

*** update ****
I tried out #make install instead of #make altinstall as recommended by @intboolstring and here is the output , in one of the screenshots you will see that is say "Python build finished successfully" but after this I am having no luck with running python3

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried `python3`?

Comment: yes Daniel, same issue when I try that too

Comment: It is not in your path, you will have to add it manually. You can verify by exporting in your shell and then running python3

Comment: the path is supposed to be the default path.../usr/local/...so I should be able to execute , right ? In any case I went to /usr/local/bin and from there tried to execute this and not much luck

Comment: What comes after `Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 7.1.2 requires SSL/TLS`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that was the last line , nothing after it

Answer (score 1):

Well, that is happening because the `python3.5` command **does not exist**.

```
python
```

will run Python 2, with

```
python3
```

running the Python 3 shell.

**When you boot up the python shell, it will say:**

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03)
```

which shows you your version number.

Comment: thx for the reply..I had run "make altisntall" I can still execute python (2.7) but not python3.5....I tried python3 also...and have attached one more screenshot to the question after your answer

Comment: Did that help you?

Comment: 1. $wget    2. $tar ... 3 #./configure   4. #make     5. #make altinstall   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4

Comment: when I did wget and tar I was in the home directory and then before the rest did a $sudo -i, and hence did it as root...not sure if that matters ? thx for any further input

Comment: Do the following: `wget --no-check-certificate http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/Python-3.5.1.tgz`, `tar -xzf Python-3.5.1.tgz `, `cd Python-3.5.1`, `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`.

Comment: that is what I had already tried...except that wget did not have no check certificate . I had executed wget and tar from home directory and then had done sudo-i before the next commands ...and yes at the end had done #make altinstall and not #make install....should I be doing #make install please ? I thought that would replace 2.7 and I do not want to do anything to 2.7...I need both 2.7 and 3.x

Comment: It won't replace it.  You want to do `sudo make install`.

Comment: I created another centos compute instance and tried the same steps and then am able to execute python3.5 (as a command) and python . but on this particular server when I try the same steps....python3.5 does not work -:( am not sure what is wrong with this server...appreciate further suggestions !